# How can I add a control to another control in C#?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I want to create a custom control by extending an existing control. In fact, I want to add some features to the original control. How can I another control (a control such as TextBox) to my custom control in its constructor or anywhere else?

```
public partial class AdvancedKnob : KnobControl
{

    private DoubleInput Field_ValueControl =  null;

    public AdvancedKnob()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Field_ValueControl = new DoubleInput();
        this.Container.Add(this.Field_ValueControl); //DOES NOT WORK!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.Field_ValueControl);
```

For more information, go to: [How to programmatically add controls to Windows forms at run time by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
this.Controls.Add(control);
```